Casting SqmLiteral to SqmExtract unit Spring boot with hibernate
I am using this predicate to get the hour out of the date time field on my postgresql database using spring boot.
     Expression<Integer> extractHourFunction = builder.function(
                    "EXTRACT",     // Function name
                    Integer.class, // Result type
                    builder.literal(ChronoUnit.HOURS;), // Extract hour
                    root.get(entityType.getSingularAttribute("meetingTime", OffsetDateTime.class)) 
            );

When i try to create the function, i get this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmLiteral cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmExtractUnit

Can anyone explain why this is happening

have you find a fix of this issue?

Have you found a fix for that? It seems that in Hibernate 6.2 they added criteriaBuilder.truncate function.
One of the Hibernate team guys proposed to directly use SqmExtractUnit:
new SqmExtractUnit<>( TemporalUnit.YEAR, ((NodeBuilder) cb).getIntegerType(), (NodeBuilder) cb ) instead of criteriaBuilder.literal("YEAR") - however I am not sure how to cast that to the .function Expression's args...

https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-use-postgres-date-trunc-via-criteriaapi-in-hibernate-6/7220/2

